# Name of soundtrack in Shippuden episode 485 when Sasuke and Orochimaru were talking in the boat

Tags: naruto, music

What is the name of the soundtrack in *Naruto Shippuden* episode 485 at 13:07 when Sasuke and Orochimaru were talking in the boat?

Answer (score 1):

This is *Sen'ya*, from Shippuden OST II track 23. Also commonly known as "Itachi's theme".